# Not able to send variables between 2 files

Tags: python, api, tkinter

**Process:**
With T1 you get a gui where you can put two licenceplate number. Those two number plates are put in kenteken1 and kenteken2. In T2 i get kenteken1 and kenteken2. I use those to get information from a API to get those cars information. In algemeen1 and algemeen2 i put the information i get. After this i want to print algemeen1 and algemeen2 in T1.

**Problem:**
I cannot get it to work.

Any suggestions to get the code working and improvements? Probably easy solution that i cannot see.

**Running the code below gives me this:**

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Shaker\PycharmProjects\RDW_Vergelijker_Shaker\T1.py", line 15, in show_entry_fields
    print_info_auto()
  File "C:\Users\Shaker\PycharmProjects\RDW_Vergelijker_Shaker\T1.py", line 18, in print_info_auto
    print(algemeen1)
NameError: name 'algemeen1' is not defined
```

T1.py

```
from tkinter import *
# from T2 import algemeen1
# from T2 import algemeen2
from T2 import *

global kenteken1
global kenteken2

def show_entry_fields():
    global kenteken1, kenteken2
    kenteken1 = Kenteken1_entry.get()
    kenteken2 = Kenteken2_entry.get()
    print_info_auto()

def print_info_auto():
    print(algemeen1)
    print(algemeen2)



master = Tk()
Label(master, text="Kenteken 1").grid(row=0)
Label(master, text="Kenteken 2").grid(row=1)

Kenteken1_entry = Entry(master)
Kenteken2_entry = Entry(master)

Kenteken1_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
Kenteken2_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

Button(master, text='Sluit', command=master.quit).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
Button(master, text='Vergelijk', command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

mainloop()
```

T2.py

```
import requests
from T1 import kenteken1
from T1 import kenteken2

entry1  = kenteken1
entry2  = kenteken2
ken1    = '&kenteken='+entry1
ken2    = '&kenteken='+entry2
token   = '$$app_token=d3j2ChpOuaeghKvy4u1C2arcO'


api_query_algemeen = "&$select= merk, handelsbenaming, voertuigsoort, inrichting, uitvoering, eerste_kleur, " \
                     "massa_rijklaar, wam_verzekerd, vervaldatum_apk, datum_eerste_toelating"


url_algemeen1 = 'https://opendata.rdw.nl/resource/m9d7-ebf2.json?{}{}{}'.format(token,api_query_algemeen,ken1)
url_algemeen2 = 'https://opendata.rdw.nl/resource/m9d7-ebf2.json?{}{}{}'.format(token,api_query_algemeen,ken2)


response = requests.get(url_algemeen1)
algemeen1 = response.json()


response = requests.get(url_algemeen2)
algemeen2 = response.json()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have circular dependencies. T1 requires `algemeen1` from T2, but T2 requires `kenteken1` and `kenteken2` from T1. Your design is fundamentally flawed.

Plus, you really shouldn't be importing something that does actual work. Imports are usually to import data, functions and classes.

There are no easy solutions for your code.

Comment: Thank you, with circular dependencies in my mind i changed the code and found a solution for my problem.